# How to separate inner class of template class into other file

Tags: c++, templates, inner-classes

I want to do:

```
typedef MyTemplateClass<Type01, Type02> TClass;
TClass t;
TClass::InnerClass i;
i.test();
```

i think the solution could be:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
class MyTemplateClass
{
public:
    class InnerClass
    {
        //here I can do stuff with A and B
        A test() { return 0; }
    };

    friend class InnerClass;
};
```

but I want to have ma templates in separate *.inl file included at the bottom of header file

how to define such behaviour in other file?

when i do just

```
//file.inl
class InnerClass
{
    //here I can do stuff with A and B
    A test() { return 0; }
};
```

A and B are undefined.

but

```
template <typename A, typename B>
class InnerClass
{
...
};
```

makes my method template independent of MyTemplateClass types...

Once again in one sentence:
How to make InnerClass of MyTemplateClass in other file with providing

```
TClass::InnerClass i;
i.test();
```

behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. In a nutshell. Templates must be wholly defined before instantiation- that means that whatever you do, you'll have to define the inner class in the template class anyway.

Answer (score 7):

It works the same as when using a non-template: you have to fully qualify the name of the member:

```
struct outer {
    struct nested;
};

struct outer::nested {
    int
    test();
};

int
outer::nested::test()
{ /* whatever */ }
```

In your case that'd be:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
class MyTemplateClass {
public:
    class InnerClass;

    friend class InnerClass;
};

// note the use of the <> brackets
template<typename A, typename B>
class MyTemplateClass<A, B>::InnerClass {
public:
    A
    test();
};

// ditto
template<typename A, typename B>
A
MyTemplateClass<A, B>::InnerClass::test()
{ return 0; }
```

You *do* have to be wary of the definition order though: if e.g. `MyTemplateClass` has function members that use `InnerClass`, then the definition of `InnerClass` has to be visible at the point of use.

Simple rule of thumb: inline everything or nothing. Either you define everything inline (the `InnerClass` class definition *and* the function members of both classes) inside `MyTemplateClass`, or you put all the definitions of all function members (of both `MyTemplateClass` and `InnerClass`) at the very end **after** `InnerClass` has been defined.

Don't fret though, if you mess up your compiler will only be too happy to help you with error messages.